# How to catch ESC in event in JQuery Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

Is it possible to have a custom handler for ESC key on the JQuery Dialog?

Comment: one is already there called closeOnEscape: false

Comment: @DipeshParmar that just turns off the default escape handler, it doesn't add a custom handler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Set the `closeOnEscape` option to `false` and register your own `keydown` handler on the `.ui-dialog` element within the dialog's `dialogcreate` handler.

```
$(element).dialog({
    create: function() {
       $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').on('keydown', function(ev) {
           if (ev.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
               ...
           }
       });
       ...
    },
    closeOnEscape: false,
    ...
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/EbnZr

Answer (score 7):

I use another way:

```
$(element).dialog({

    beforeClose: function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
            // ...
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector-for-dialog).keyup(function(e) {
    // ESC key
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) {
        // custom action
    }
});
```